# Date Range Query in Mongoose Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am facing this issue after converting to momentJS and then searching in Database. It is showing me the following error in catch block

> Converting circular structure to JSON\n    --> starting at object with
> constructor 'NativeTopology'\n    |     property 's' -> object with
> constructor 'Object'\n    |     property 'sessionPool' -> object with
> constructor 'ServerSessionPool'\n    --- property 'topology' closes
> the circle

```
const getAppointmentByDate = async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    //get dates from req.query by es6 object destructuring
 
 
   //1. check that date is not empty
 
   //2. check that date is in the right format
  //expected result: YYY-MMM-DDD

    reqDate = new Date("1-1-2021")

    var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T00:00:00.000Z]');
    console.log("Next day -- " + (reqDate.getDate() + 1))
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(reqDate.getDate() + 1);
    var tomorrow = moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T00:00:00.000Z]');
 
 //In some cases you'll get a date-time format where you have to separate the date
 //from the time.
 
  const transactions = Appointment.find({  
    "schedule_datetime": {
      "$gte": new Date(today),
      "$lt": new Date(tomorrow)
    }
  })

 //4. Handle responses
 if(!transactions) {
 return res.status(404).json({
  status:'failure',
  message:'Could not retrieve transactions'
 })
 }
 
 
 res.status(200).json({
 status:'success',
 data: transactions
    })
 
 } catch(error) {
   return res.status(500).json({
      status:'failure',
      error: error.message
         })
  }

  }
```

Comment: Can you tell from which line in your code, this error gets emitted? Figure it out by insert `console.log(1)` before each suspicious line, and check when this line is not consoled. I reckon inserting it before `cons transcations = ....`

Comment: You create `Date` and convert to string back an forth. Why not simply `schedule_datetime: {$gte: moment().startOf('day').toDate(), $lt: moment().startOf('day').add(1,'day').toDate() }`?

Comment: `new Date("1-1-2021")` is wrong format. Must be `new Date("2021-01-01")`, see [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score 0):

```
const getAppointmentByDate = async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    //get dates from req.query by es6 object destructuring
 
 
   //1. check that date is not empty
 
   //2. check that date is in the right format
  //expected result: YYY-MMM-DDD

    reqDate = new Date("1-1-2021")

    var today = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T00:00:00.000Z]');
    console.log("Next day -- " + (reqDate.getDate() + 1))
    var d = new Date();
    d.setDate(reqDate.getDate() + 1);
    var tomorrow = moment(d).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T00:00:00.000Z]');
 
 //In some cases you'll get a date-time format where you have to separate the date
 //from the time.
 
  const transactions = Appointment.find({  
    "schedule_datetime": {
      "$gte": new Date(today),
      "$lt": new Date(tomorrow)
    }
  })



transactions.each((err, item) => {
            //error handling
            //console.log(item)
            if (err) {
                  console.log(err)
                  return res.status(500).json({
                        isSuccess: false,
                        data: {},
                        message: errorcodes.error_500,
                        status: 500,
                  });
            }
            //pushing it into array
            if (item != null) {
 
                  delete item._id;
                  result.push(item);
            } else {
                  res.status(200).json({ "data": result });
            }
      })
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.